# Shortcut to open a particular website

Tags: neovim, command-line, external-command

I'm using neovim on mac os, in case that information is of use.

In the shell I have some aliases such as

```sh
alias g='open HTTP://google.com
```

For sites that I access regularly, I would like to be able to have a similar shortcut available within vim, but I'm not sure how to go about this. I'm on mac os (which is why the command is usually `open`).

I have tried:

```sh
:! open https://vi.stackexchange.com/
```

Which *does* open stack exchange in a new tab (which is good), but it also puts some output into my vim command pallette which is not wanted.

```
:! open https://vi.stackexchange.com/
[No write since last change]

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The above is in the command pallette, which makes me think that there's likely a better approach.

### Edit

Perhaps the following is the correct approach:

```sh
:silent exec "!open https://vi.stackexchange.com/"
```

### Edit 2

The following is an example of something that doesn't work unless it's quoted:

doesn't work:

```sh
:silent !open https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA2WjJbmmoM&feature=youtu.be&t=2578
```

works:

```sh
:silent !open 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA2WjJbmmoM&feature=youtu.be&t=2578'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `exec` in your command. `!open <URL>` in itself is a complete command recognized by Vim. So simply,

`:silent !open https://vi.stackexchange.com/`
is sufficient!

EDIT: As OP mentioned edits so here is a detailed explanation of why URLs containing ampersand `&` won't work without using either quotes or escape character.

In OP's edit 2 part 1, the ampersand `&` is used to repeat last substitute in Ex-mode. So using that URL without quotes, Vim will interpret it as multiple Ex-mode commands separated by `&`. You can get the desired output by replacing `&` with `\&` inside URL. But I would suggest to use quotes.

Comment: thanks - I have added an example of where things break as well (so - i think perhaps this is solved now? Unless there's anything additional to do around best practices or such)

Comment: That's right. In Edit 2, part 1 the ampersand `&` is used to repeat last substitute in Ex-mode. So using that URL without quotes, Vim will interpret it as multiple Ex-mode commands separated by `&`. You can get the desired output by replacing `&` with `\&` inside URL. But I would suggest to use quotes.

Comment: cheers - if you could stick the comment into the answer that'd make it more complete imo, thanks though